# HTML the length of text inside <p> tag is not the same as code editor

Tags: html

About HTML: as shown in the picture. I have two p tags with the same length of text in textEditor, but they display different length in HTML, can any one tell me the reason, Thank you !
[image]

Comment: Try googling "difference between monospaced and proportional fonts"

Comment: The difference is not about the length of the text. As @j08691 mentioned, it's a font related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. This contrasts with variable-width fonts, where the letters and spacings have different widths.

(from [Monospaced font - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font))

Your editor on the left is using a **monospaced** font whereas the rendered HTML on the right uses a **variable-width** font.

Comment: Thank you very much